# Kill the currently active window with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kill, xdotools

How can I kill the currently active window with a command or keyboard shortcut?

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> *closes* a window, but first it will wait for the program to respond. Depending on the application, this may take several minutes. I am specifically interested in a solution with no waiting period -- that is, a solution that takes effect instantly.

I want to immediately kill the currently focused window with a shortcut.

Comment: On certain KDE applications in Linux, Ctrl+w closes the current focused window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool) to kill the currently active window:

```
xdotool getwindowfocus windowkill
```

On Ubuntu, make a keyboard shortcut:

1. Open Keyboard settings (shown below).
2. Create a shortcut with the command: `xdotool getwindowfocus windowkill`

I chose: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

This shortcut will kill the currently active window *immediately*. It will *not* wait for the application to respond, terminate, save, close files, finish up, etc.

[image: Keyboard Settings]

Comment: thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 18):

I think you are looking for [`xkill`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.0/doc/html/xkill.1.html).

Start it in a shell, then click on the offending window.

Alternatively, you can do <kbd>Alt-F4</kbd> and wait - then you will be asked

```
the program is not responding - terminate it? (you will lose unsaved work)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would prefer to use a keyboard shortcut instead of opening a shell, typing a command, and then using my mouse to find the window. When I open a shell, it might overlap or hide the offending window. I think it's much easier to use a shortcut.

Comment: In that case you should use Alt-F4 or click on the "x" in the upper right(or left) corner. After a while, you will be asked the "terminate it?" question.

Comment: In theory, you're right. In practice, I don't have time to wait for the application to respond. Sometimes it takes minutes before such a "terminate it?" question pops up. After clicking "terminate it" then I have to wait even longer. I'm looking specifically for a solution that avoids waiting.

Comment: It is far too easy to "mis-click", so such a dangerous action as killing an application will never be easy.

Comment: what about ctrl+q? That closes the active window (i guess with signal SIGTERM). On Windows is ctrl+w.

Answer (score 6):

The default kill-window shortcut for me in **KDE** is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

[image]

(There's a separate <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> "close window" entry)

System Settings -> Shortcuts and Gestures -> Global Keyboard Shortcuts -> KWin

Comment: As of 2023, that shortcut is `Meta/Super` + `Ctrl` + `Esc` in KDE.